# How to implement merge conflict preview using libgit2?

Tags: libgit2

I'm trying to implement a content management website, in many ways, it's like a simplified github.

the version control and collaboration part is based on git using libgit2.

But I can't find how to implement merge conflict preview, that would tell an user if her change is clean to merge or not and which lines have conflict.

the example here https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/examples/merge.c

performs merging with the git_merge function, however, this function would directly alter the current index.

I also checked a github open source alternative, but I forgot its name now. That project used a library from the eclipse ide, which provides a conflict preview feature.

How should I implement this with libgit2 and is there an example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, the `git_merge` function mutates the working directory and the index.  You can use the `git_merge_commits` function to do an in-memory merge of two commits and return the resulting index.

You can then iterate over the index looking for conflicts or simply call [`git_index_has_conflicts`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/include/git2/index.h#L792) if you only want to know if conflicts exist.

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question regarding git_merge_commit, do both commits the latest commit of the 2 repositories. Suppose I want to merge 3 top commits from repo B to repo A, what I need to pass into this function is the latest commit?

Comment: This doesn't _cherry-pick_ a commit, it merges two branches, but those two branches don't need to have a branch pointing to them.  eg, if you had `HEAD` pointing to `1af6744` and you had `branch` pointing to `89bca51` then `git_merge_commits(out, repo, 1af6744, 89bca51...)` is the equivalent of running `git merge branch` on the command-line.